# First version of Strong Law - finite vs bounded

Tags: probability-theory, definition, probability-limit-theorems

Iirc, bounded functions are finite and not all finite functions are bounded.

From Williams' Probability w/ Martingales:

[image]

Why 'finite 4th moment' ? It's technically right I guess, but why not 'bounded 4th moment' ?

Comment: In my view "bounded" is better as otherwise you might have $X_n$ taking the values $\pm n$ with equal probability, so with fourth moment $n^4$ which is finite for each $n$, but where $S_n/n$ does not converge.

Comment: @Henry Guess so. Thanks. But the book says finite instead of bounded... :|

Comment: It does, but it then uses $K$ as an upper bound

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1   up voted
    flag
In my view "bounded" is better as otherwise you might have XnXn taking the values ±n±n with equal probability, so with fourth moment n4n4 which is finite for each nn, but where Sn/nSn/n does not converge. – Henry Nov 3 at 13:26

@Henry Guess so. Thanks. But the book says finite instead of bounded... :| – BCLC Nov 7 at 8:48

It does, but it then uses KK as an upper bound – Henry Nov 7 at 14:59